# Testing Clojure's comp function

Tags: clojure

I've been re-implementing some Clojure functions in another language, using the tests a reference and I'm kinda confused by [the tests](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/bc186508ab98514780efbbddb002bf6fd2938aee/test/clojure/test_clojure/other_functions.clj#L78) for [`clojure.core/comp`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/comp).

```
(deftest test-comp
  (let [c0 (comp)]
    (are [x] (= (identity x) (c0 x))
         nil
         42
         [1 2 3]
         #{}
         :foo)
    (are [x y] (= (identity x) (c0 y))
         (+ 1 2 3) 6
         (keyword "foo") :foo)))
```

`comp` itself is only used once and with no arguments. That behaviour doesn't seem to be documented, but [the source](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.7.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L2426) shows that it just returns the `identity` function.

```
(defn comp
  ([] identity)
  ([f] f)
  ([f g] 
     (fn 
       ([] (f (g)))
       ([x] (f (g x)))
       ([x y] (f (g x y)))
       ([x y z] (f (g x y z)))
       ([x y z & args] (f (apply g x y z args)))))
  ([f g & fs]
     (reduce1 comp (list* f g fs))))
```

Does this mean that 3/4 of these arities aren't tested? Or are there tests kept somewhere else? I found these tests through a GitHub search and they aren't always totally reliable.

Why does the zero arity form have tests, when it would seem like the least useful variant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes. It's only tested here. In fact, there were no tests for `comp` until the zero-arg version is added in v1.3.0. Check this [commit](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/commit/140a9866646d60158da485e6229d3afba01dcb4c) and its [parent](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/commit/73453f2ed5f23e84ba779b7824dd0ea12bec1bff).
2. The zero-arg `comp` is useful, it helps in eliminating trivial branching code for corner cases. Suppose you want to conduct a series of transformations to a given input. But these transformations are dynamically generated, and it can degrade to a point where no transformation should be done.

EDIT:
To provide an example on my point 2:

```
(defn my-format
  "Returns an HTML representation of the given text in a paragraph,
   supports `:b' for bold and `:i' for italic font, and possibly more
   in the future."
  [text & more-args]
  (let [wrap (fn [w t] (str "<" w ">" t "</" w ">"))]
    (wrap "p" ((apply comp 
                      (map #(partial wrap (name %)) more-args))
               text)))
; => (my-format "hello world" :b :i)
; "<p><b><i>hello world</i></b></p>
; => (my-format "hello world")
; "<p>hello world</p>
```

The code snippet is trivial, but you get the idea. If `comp` does not support the 0-arity version, the code would not look so elegant.

Comment: Don't quite follow point two. Any chance you could add a quick example?

Comment: @DanPrince Updated the answer, HTH